# How to get proper params through ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I want pass full object of data to controller through ajax call, but params are not getting proper format. below is my ajax code.

```
function fileUpdate(){
var values = []
skill = $("#skill").val();
var cnf = confirm("Are you sure？");
if ( cnf == true) {
$.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: '/user_skill_update',
      dataType: 'json',
      data:  { skill: skill},
      success: function (msg) {
      },
      error: function (err){
        console.log(err)       
      }   
    });
    $('#reset')[0].click();
    alert(skill);
}
```

}

```
   # use object to pass through ajax call
  <%= hidden_field_tag :skill, value: @data %> 
  <%= button_to "update", 'javascript:void(0)', id:'updateFileRank', class: 'btn btn-info btn-xl', style:"margin-top: 80px;margin-left:-26px;", onclick: 'fileUpdate();' %>


   # ouput
   {"skill"=>"{:value=>[{\"dept_id\"=>\"01\", \"user_id\"=>\"001\", \"level_cd\"=>\"04_swim\", \"first_name\"=>\"rohit\", \"last_name\"=>\"patel\", \"dept_full_name\"=>\"swiming\", \"rank\"=>\"04_swim\"}, {\"dept_id\"=>\"02\", \"user_id\"=>\"002\", \"level_cd\"=>\"04_swim\", \"first_name\"=>\"ranjit\", \"last_name\"=>\"shinde\", \"dept_full_name\"=>\"running\", \"rank\"=>\"03_run\"}, {\"dept_id\"=>\"04\", \"user_id\"=>\"004\", \"level_cd\"=>\"02_jump\", \"first_name\"=>\"kedar\", \"last_name\"=>\"patil\", \"dept_full_name\"=>\"jumping\", \"rank\"=>\"02_jump\"}, {\"dept_id\"=>\"05\", \"user_id\"=>\"005\", \"level_cd\"=>\"03_run\", \"first_name\"=>\"kapil\", \"last_name\"=>\"bote\", \"dept_full_name\"=>\"Hammer\", \"rank\"=>\"03_run\"}



   # I need this format output.
  {"skill"=>"{:value=>[{"dept_id"=>"01", "user_id"=>"001", "level_cd"=>"04_swim", "first_name"=>"rohit", "last_name"=>"patel", "dept_full_name"=>"swiming", "rank"=>"04_swim"}, {"dept_id"=>"02", "user_id"=>"002", "level_cd"=>"04_swim", "first_name"=>"ranjit", "last_name"=>"shinde", "dept_full_name"=>"running", "rank"=>"03_run"}, {"dept_id"=>"04", "user_id"=>"004", "level_cd"=>"02_jump", "first_name"=>"kedar", "last_name"=>"patil", "dept_full_name"=>"jumping", "rank"=>"02_jump"}, {"dept_id"=>"05", "user_id"=>"005", "level_cd"=>"03_run", "first_name"=>"kapil", "last_name"=>"bote", "dept_full_name"=>"Hammer", "rank"=>"03_run"}
```

Comment: Your output is in JSON.  Just use a rails helper to decode it:  ActiveSupport::JSON.decode("#{@data}")

Comment: Output converted in proper, but not updating data and giving error "JSON::ParserError - 822: unexpected token at "

Comment: The value you are getting from $(“skil”) is a string. Did you try something like @data.as_json? My guess is the @data is still in ruby hash format and when you call for value it converts everything to string and that could be leading to an error since json parser is expecting a json formatted string. If as_json doesn’t work then try to_json as well on data

Comment: as_json and to_json are not giving proper value as i want. ActiveSupport::JSON.decode("#{@data}") is giving but puting error "JSON::ParserError - 822: unexpected token at "

Comment: Like I said, :value is not valid json format and that could be causing this error. Also, you have mix of hash and json in your expected output and on top of it it is inside double quotes. You need to change your logic here. The proper format here is a pure json and that’s what you should aim for.

Comment: Agree with Abhinay, `value` is creating trouble

Comment: Agree with @Abhinay , but I didn't understant, also i have checked removing value and other's tried, still same error giving JSON::ParserError - 822: unexpected token at "

Comment: something like this: `"key": "value" ` is a valid format here and removing just `value` from data would still leave the data in `[{"dept_id"=>"01", "user_id"=>"001"...]` in this format which is still not a valid format because of `=>`. It is a ruby hash syntax.

Comment: I think your controller logic should expect a JSON and parse it accordingly. converting @data in a JSON format should solve your issue. :)